# C# verify user in Active Directory from Socket conection

Tags: c#, security, sockets, active-directory

I am a .Net developer since its first days. But the last time was quite interesting. I wrote an network basics dll for my own purpose and started to write the fitting iOS client apps. Everything works fine but now I kind of thought about not managing the user data myself, but to use the existing data of the Active Directory. It would not be any kind of problem to send the plain text username and password from the app to the server and do the verification then, but that is not as safe as I want it to be. My personal most preferred way would be:

1. send username from app to server
2. get challenged password hash from the AD by the username and the challenge
3. send the challenge to the client
4. hash the password with the challenge
5. send back the hash to the server and check if the hashes are matching

Quite simple straight forward way. I do not have to deal with certificates and can provide a basic security. I know, that in modern times it is not the topmost safe way. But it is sufficient for my needs.

My question is, is there a way to get the hashed password for a user from the ad and do I get the challenge? Or is there an other simple way to provide a easy secure way of verifying an user not in the local network?

Thank you very much in advance

Best regards
Florian

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement? It's very simple to verify a login:

```
bool authenticated;
using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
{
    authenticated = domainContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is the way, I would verify a user of which I have the credentials present locally. But to get these credentials I need to transfer them over an unsecure socket connection. I do not want to transfer the password as plain text. That's why I want to implement the way discribed above.

Answer (score 0):

As you said this should be a basic authentication but without sending plain password over network. Therefor I would suggest a solution with an asymmetric encryption.

Encrypting the password on client side and send the encrypted message to the server. The server is the only one having the private key and could therefore read the password and validate it with `PrincipalContexts ValidateCredentials` methods (like itsme86 suggests).

So the steps for your application could be:

1. ask for public key from app to server
2. get public key from server
3. encrypt password with public key
4. send back the encrypted password together with the user name to the server
5. server decrypts the credentials and validates them against the AD